# Error message when trying to downvote to retract accidental upvote

Tags: support, downvotes, voting, privileges

I was reading a question on Stack Overflow, and by accident I upvoted it (my cat jumped on my computer and clicked the mouse).

I know that this is a 1 in a million situation, but still I feel like users should be able to retract their upvotes. But when I click on the down arrow to retract my upvote, it says I don't have reputation enough to do so.

Comment: Too bad, now you need a new mouse.  Keep that cat away!

Comment: You can undo your vote in the first five minutes by clicking the upvote arrow again.

Comment: Just another piece of evidence that cats are evil.

Comment: Or the cat has a better sense of quality than the OP @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You undo an upvote by clicking on the upvote button a second time, not [just] by clicking on the downvote button.  Of course, if you *did* have enough reputation to downvote, then clicking on the downvote button *would* retract the upvote in the process of adding a downvote.

And of course, a downvote can be retracted by clicking the downvote button a second time.

Note that votes (in either direction) can only be retracted within a few minutes of being cast, unless the post has been edited.

Comment: "Note that votes (in either direction) can only be retracted within a few minutes of being cast" And why is _that_? It can take longer than "a few minutes" to realize you've made a mistake.

Comment: @matt To prevent abuse, in which a user casts a vote in order to push a particular answer closer to the top, where it will have more attention, only to later retract the vote after the attention gives that answer enough votes to stay there.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of that. I guess I need to start gaming the system more. :)

Comment: For as long as I've been a member, I did not know that... Odd behavior from the site because it so un-intuitive.