# New buttons - "Click again to undo" instead of just clicking the opposite button -- what is the support for it?

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface, user-experience

I recently voted on a question on SO, then reconsidered my vote as there was subtleties that were not needed. When I went to retract my vote in the normal way by clicking the opposite arrow, the vote jumped from `1` to `-1` without going to `0`. That was quite a surprise.

After trying again just to make sure a simultaneous additional downvote wasn't received at the same time by utter coincidence, it became clear this was the behavior of the two buttons.

Poking around, the "click again to undo" tooltip displayed - Huh? That provided the solution but brought up this question:

*What design pattern justifies using the same button on what is essentially a spin-button to undo?*

I've used the web since before Mosiac appeared and used many desktop UI toolkits and have never seen that behavior before. Is there a specific pattern that says that makes sense? If so, where is it documented? If not, why do we do it that way?

Comment: *"When I went to retract my vote in the normal way by clicking the opposite arrow..."* This has never been the *normal* way. I don't even think it worked... It *switched* your vote to the opposite direction, just like it does now.

Comment: Indeed, as I thought, it has always worked this way, See [proof from back in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253768). This is *not* a change introduced with the vote button redesign. If you were previously retracting upvotes by clicking the downvote button, you've been inadvertently downvoting a bunch of posts...

Comment: "*Is there a specific pattern that says that makes sense? If so, where is it documented? If not, why do we do it that way?*" perhaps that's a question for [ux.se]...

Comment: _"and have never seen that behavior before"_ How about Reddit and YouTube (before they hid the dislike count)? And almost all online voting systems that I can think of. I don't really think it makes sense otherwise. Perhaps you're confusing cumulative voting with up/down arrows that are used to increment/decrement the value of a field (where the objective is setting the value, as opposed to voting)?

Comment: I must be going crazy then (always possible), because I recall using the down-arrow to roll back votes. Perhaps infants Alzheimer's is setting in.... Still an odd way to go.

Comment: No, I agree. The confusion is real. Perhaps it comes from the buttons being highlighted when hovered over? That is, it looks like a state change, but it isn't. Our brains have to get used to it.

Answer (score 7):

The voting buttons have always functioned in that manner on this site.

When you click on the upvote button, it becomes highlighted (toggled on) indicating that your vote has been registered. To retract your vote, you click on the same button to toggle it off.

Clicking the downvote button reverses your vote in the opposite direction.

Comment: I appreciate the information. I don't recall the buttons remaining highlighted until the egg buttons showed up recently. I don't retract many votes, so it's not something I do frequently. Are you sure it has always been this way over the past 9 years?

Comment: It has been like that as far as i can recall. My account is 10 years old

Comment: Fair enough, the intent was a `[discussion]` on the wisdom of clicking an Up-Arrow (which implies a direction) to go down. I don't care how it works, it just struct me as wrong to imply an increase with an arrow only to have the arrow work in the opposite direction than shown. Just making the circles into round buttons would at least minimize the implied direction (though it would still persist to some degree due to the Up/Down vertical arrangement) Who knew, click UP to go up, and click UP again to go down -- that's the awkward part of the logic. Maybe it's just the engineer in me...